# rails array sort based on availability

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Here is my post controller

```
  def refine id
    @sub_category_content = Post.where(sub_category_id: id).select('content')
    chained_array = []

    @sub_category_content.each do |content|
      form_chain = JSON.parse(content.content)
      chained_array << form_chain.values
    end

    @refine = chained_array.flatten.uniq

  end
```

Here is my application controller helper

```
def bypass_block refine, list
    refine = refine.include? list
    if refine
      'active'
    else
      'inactive'
    end
  end
```

Here is my view

```
<% label.dropdown_lists.each do |list| %>
    <li>
    <% style = bypass_block(@refine, list.list_name) %>
    <a class="<%= style %>">
        <input type="checkbox" class="<%= style %>" />
        <%= list.list_name %>
    </a>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

@refine will through the array as `["test","test123","tet22","abc","cds","sdd","cds"]`

Consider my list name will pass following values in loop `tks, abc, ssld, cds, test`

So in loop i will get output as

**Actual output**

1. tks
2. abc
3. ssld
4. cds
5. test

**Expected output**

1. abc
2. cds
3. test
4. tks
5. ssld

How can i perform such a sorting here.

**Edit - 1**

.sort is working in this

```
<% @models.sort.each do |product_model| %>
<% for_style = product_model.posts.any? ? 'active' : 'inactive' %>
<li class="auto-view">
<a class="<%= for_style %>">
<input type="checkbox" class="<%= for_style %>" />
<%= product_model.name %>
</a>
</li>
<% end %>
```

But in the above array case it is not working

After using `@refine = chained_array.flatten.sort.uniq`

[image]

I think only the color is not working it seems

Comment: `label.dropdown_lists.sort.each`

Comment: @apneadiving can you please check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Could you set

```
@refine = chained_array.flatten.sort.uniq
```

in the controller?

Comment: Can you please checkout my screenshot

Comment: It is not sorting i tried by adding year 2011 it is also showing same as color

Comment: What i feel is it is sorting in the array and not from values in view's loop right?